# Red gate SQL compare for Backups doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, redgate

I need some help from Red Gate users.

I am trying to compare 2 database backups. After I selected the 2 backups, the "compare now" button is not active and it also says "Backup sets are not selected".

Please take a look at the screenshot.

http://screencast.com/t/O62m66flA

Do you know what am I missing here? or did I understand this functionality wrong?

Thanks,
RM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also have problems if the database is encrypted.

Comment: The database backup is 1 FULL BACKUP. But it is encrypted using TDE. So I think this is why it cannot be accessed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not very good but offhand I'd say that the backup files you have provided are not a full set of backups. For data comparing BAK files, the content could be one or a combination of full backups, differential backups, or log backups. If there isn't at least a full backup in there, the backup set is incomplete.

The BAK may just contain a differential or log backup, so Data Compare would be unable to reconstruct a database schema for which to associate the pages of data in the backup.